# Table view content jumping down when using UIRefreshControl and setting contentInset

Tags: ios, ios6, uitableview, uirefreshcontrol

So I have standard subclass of UITableViewController with table view. Now I have set content inset to

```
self.tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(40, 0, 0, 0);
```

I'm also using UIRefreshControl in standard way.

```
self.refreshControl = [[CTRefreshControl alloc] init];
[self.refreshControl addTarget:self action:@selector(loadData:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
```

All works fine and smoothly if table view contains enough data that it scrolls(so content size height is more than table view's height). When there is not enough data in table (e.g. only 2 rows) then when I start to pull down it goes smoothly and then suddenly it jumps by about 20 points down. Same thing happens when I scroll other direction. It doesn't happen when there's no refresh control or when I don't change contentInset. Any ideas? All on iOS 6.

Comment: Put the change of contentInset in an animation block with a duration of 0.2 seconds.

Comment: Why are you changing the content inset of the table view? There might be a better way of doing this without changing the content inset.

Comment: Yes, I too have had the same problem. It's clearly a bug in iOS. I have submitted it to Apple and they have acknowledged it.

Comment: Michal ever find a solution to this? @Accatyyc, have a radar number for it?

Comment: @jasongregori It's not on open radar since the bug was resolved somewhere in the iOS7 beta. I don't think there's a solution for iOS6...

Answer (score 1):

You need to put the change of contentInset in an animation block like this...

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.2
                      delay:0.0
                    options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseInOut
                 animations:^{
                     self.tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(40, 0, 0, 0);
                 }
                 completion:nil];
```

(Typed from memory so you may have to check code completion).

This should fix your problem.

Comment: I'm setting contentInset in viewDidLoad as content should always stay 40 pips lower(unless you scroll) so this doesn't have any effect.

Comment: Setting the content inset in Interface Builder instead of viewDidLoad should see the content inset applied and UITableViewController incorporating it in the offset.